# How to pass an option containing a space to a package in LaTeX/XeLaTeX

Tags: latex, tex, xelatex

When I declare an option containing a space, LaTeX/XeLaTeX eats it.

In the main .tex, I have :

```
\usepackage[test font]{test}
```

In my .sty file I have :

```
\DeclareOption*{\newfontfamily\testfont[Scale=1]{\CurrentOption}}
\ProcessOptions
```

But the Tex engine passes to the package **testfont** option and not **test font**.

So the question is how to pass the option containing the space to the package.

Answer (score 7):

Protect it with braces

```
\usepackage[{test font}]{test}
```

Comment: I was forgetting that you'd actually need two sets of braces here:

\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{test.sty}
\def\Options{}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \edef\Options{\Options,\CurrentOption}
  \AtBeginDocument{\Options}
}
\ProcessOptions
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[{{option here}}]{test}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, the kernel does the space stripping before your package gets at anything. The usual alternative is not to take the data at package loading but have a set up macro that processes things after loading. That avoids loosing spaces.

Comment: Yes with 2 braces it works, but I can't ask the user to do this.

Comment: Hence my suggestion of not taking the options at load time, and instead having a preamble-only macro which does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\catcode`\ =11
\usepackage[test font]{test}
\catcode`\ =10
```

This is quite likely to fail, but the failure might be progress on what we have so far.

Comment: Yes this will fail, but with a little change it will compile without error :

in the .tex file
\catcode`\ =11
\usepackage[test font]{test}

and in the .sty file

\DeclareOption*{\typeout{What's  \CurrentOption}}
\ProcessOptions
\catcode`\ =10

The problem being that moving the first catcode in the .sty file doesn't work.